# git + go - how to handle subprojects with go get

Tags: git, go, git-submodules

I use the version control system `git` for my software. And "within" the source code, I use `go get` to automatically fetch software from github. How can I handle the "double git" situation?

When I run `git add` on the directory `src/github.com/somename/someproject`, which is a git repository in itself, will this add anything? (it doesn't look like this when I run `git status`)

Should I use `git submodule` for the `git get` added subdirectories?

What is the best practice in this situation?

---

Edit: I do have a custom `$GOPATH` environment for my software project. This is why the `src/github.com/somename/someproject` directory is found inside my software directory hierarchy.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I am tempted to get rid of the `.git` directory in the mentioned `github.com/somename/someproject` subdirectory. That way I just freeze the code and push it into my main repository. Ugly but I guess that works fine.

Comment: Looks like goven (https://github.com/kr/goven) does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @nemo's answer is probably the way to go, this is what I did: I stripped the `.git` and `.gitignore` files from the `go get` downloaded repositories. The source path I have is inside my source directory: `GOPATH=.../myproject/src/go/`. That way all the `go get` downloads are inside my project tree and I can just handle it with git.

I think that this is what "goven" (see my comment on my question) is supposed to do, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the revision of the foreign packages you use, it would be best if the
go import remote syntax would support something like `github.com/user/project/sub/directory/revision`, which it doesn't unfortunately. There's a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/0avuiWURSQk) on the golang-nuts mailing list about this very topic, check it out for possible solutions and caveats.

The simplest way to do this, is probably to fork the projects you use and import your forks, so you have full control over updates. Platforms like github make it really easy to do so.

From `go help remote`:

> New downloaded packages are written to the first directory
>   listed in the GOPATH environment variable (see 'go help gopath').

So your proposed submodule solution is possible but is not as easy to use, as you have to specify a custom GOPATH while fetching. I would recommend forking the library and referencing the fork.